# Existence of limit of function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$f(x)$ is a real function such that for every $a>0$ is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(an)=0$. Does there necessarily exist $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, let $(x_k)_{k\geq 1}$ be a sequence of rationally independent reals with $\lim_k x_k=+\infty$ and define the function $f(x)=1$ if $x=x_k$ some $k$ and zero otherwise. Then for any $a>0$ there is at most one value of $n$ for which $f(an)>0$. So $f$ verifies the condition but does not converge at infinity.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding a flaw in this logic. If $\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} f(an) = 0$ for every $a > 0$ then we can let $a = 1$ and we will have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0$. Why does $\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} f(n) \neq \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ need not exist (like in my example). If the limit exists it is, of course, zero.

Comment: I see why your example works as a counter example, I just can't see the flaw in the above logic. Why is there a difference between $\lim_x$ and $\lim_n$? Are $x$ and $n$ not just dummy variables?

Comment: Tempting but no. Take e.g. $f(x)=\sin (2\pi x)$ then $f(n)=0$ so $\lim_n f(n)=0$ (n here being an integer) but $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ does not exist. In general, the existence of $\lim_x$ implies that of $\lim_n$ but not the other way around.

Comment: So in that case the distinction between $x$ and $n$ is that $x$ varies over the reals and $n$ varies over the integers. Is that assumed to be the case here. When $n$ is the variable is it implied that $n$ varies over the integers?

Comment: The question is slightly ambiguous.  Although it is traditional to use $n$ to denote  the index of a sequence (which is a natural number), OP should have made it explicit (if indeed that is what was meant). Note we write $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=L$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$ for all sequences $(x_n)$  in the domain of the function converging to $x$.

Comment: Ok, I see the point. Indeed the question of the OP doesn't make sense unless we interpret $n$ to be integer valued, so this is what I took for granted.

Answer (score 1):

no! consider the function $$f(n+\frac{1}{p})=\frac{p}{n-p}$$ where $p$ is prime, $n\in \mathbb{N},n>p$, and $0$ otherwise.

then if $a\notin \mathbb{Q}$, or $a\leq 0$, then $\forall n, f(an)=0$,

and if $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ it has a finity number of prime factors. let the largest be $P$. and let $0<\epsilon<1$.
then $$an=n+1/p \Rightarrow  p\leq P $$and so $$an>2P\dfrac{1}{\epsilon} \Rightarrow  |f(an)|<\dfrac{P}{2P\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}-P}<\dfrac{P}{P\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}}=\epsilon$$ which gives $$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(an)=0$$

but, $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\neq 0$, because for $b_n=p_n+\dfrac{1}{p_n}$, where $p_n$ is the enumeration of primes, $$f(b_{n}) = \dfrac{p_n}{p_n+\dfrac{1}{p_n}-p_n}=p_n^2$$